# Approximating a function online

Tags: functions, optimization, convex-optimization

I have a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and as time goes by I get an input $x_t$ and, by feeding it through $f$ I obtain an output $y_t = f(x_t)$. There is no noise, this is a deterministic function.

> How can I approximate this function at time step $\tau$? What is this task called? (online regressio?). What are some example algorithms to perform this and what is the current state of the art?

I would like to find a method that can be udated at each time step.This is what I mean:

- $t=1$: I receive $x_1$ and I obtain $y_1 = f(x_1)$. I use the pair $(x_1, y_1)$ to learn a first approximation $\hat{f}_1$
- $t=2$: I receive $x_2$ and I obtain $y_2 = f(x_2)$. I use $\{(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2)\}$ to update $\hat{f}_1$ to $\hat{f}_2$.
- $t=\tau$: I receive $x_\tau$ and I obtain $y_\tau = f(x_\tau)$. I use $\{(x_t, y_t)\}_{t=1}^{\tau}$ to update $\hat{f}_{\tau-1}$ to $\hat{f}_\tau$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the method of [divided differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divided_differences) which approximates $f$ with a polynomial. Each of your coefficients can be updated pretty quickly each time you add a single point.

Comment: Are you aware of any python implementation of such methods?

Comment: I'm not sure, although they keywords to look for would be "polynomial interpolation" and specifically you want to find a "divided differences" (or sometimes called "Newton's divided difference formula") method with the capability to update your coefficients. Also, in the very worst-case scenario, you could always code it up yourself. This is usually a homework problem for introductory numerical analysis classes. Reference book:  Walter Gautschi, Numerical Analysis

Comment: A quick search yielded this resource too: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/newtons-divided-difference-interpolation-formula/

Comment: Thank you so much. Do you know much about other methods such as splines or Gaussian processes that would work online?

Comment: @Physics_Student not so much about Gaussian processes. But yeah, splines could also work. Often cubic splines are done in a piecewise way, so if your data comes in in an ordered fashion (e.g. $x_1 < x_2 < x_3< \ldots$) then you could build a new cubiic spline every few data points that feeds in. If it's not ordered, there would probably require some fancy footwork, because then partitioning your nodes becomes a problem.